# Choice of optimum databases for Item and Cost use case

Tags: database

Use case

- Primary index -  random string (unique entry)
- Secondary index - random string (there can be hundreds of thousands of rows with same value)

I want to update using primary index but query using secondary index.

Sample
Item and cost

Primary index is item and secondary index is cost, millions of items will have same cost and I need to figure out what items have cost X.

Comment: There is no "correct".  You can use a relational database or a NoSQL database.  The choice depends on what you're familiar with and what databases are available to you to use.  I remember back in the day when databases didn't even exist, and we had to use VSAM files to simulate a database.

Comment: Also, we're not from India, so please try to avoid using Indian words like "lakh"

Answer (score 0):

We selected mongo db after running extensive proof of concept on various databases.
AWS document db is in parity with mongodb and is available out of the box for use (AWS managed solution).